# Python exercise: Calculates the minimum and maximum score for each student.

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, min

total beginner to programming here, need your guidance.

I'm learning python from some free online course, then come across this particular exercise, which I already solved, but puzzling me having two different way produce different result. So here it goes..

The question:
Using the text file studentdata.txt (shown below) write a program that calculates the minimum and maximum score for each student. Print out their name as well.

> studentdata.txt: 
>   joe 10 15 20 30 40 
>   bill 23 16 19 22 
>   sue 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17 
>   grace 12 28 21 45 26 10 
>   john 14 32 25 16 89

My final attempt:

```
xFile = open("studentdata.txt", "r")

for xLine in xFile:
    xList = xLine.split()
    min = 100
    max = 0

    for x in xList[1:]:
        if int(x) > max:
            max = int(x)
    for x in xList[1:]:
        if int(x) < min:
            min = int(x)

print(xList[0],"\tmin: ",min,"\tmax: ",max)

xFile.close()
```

Result:

> joe    min:  10    max:  40
>   bill   min:  16    max:  23
>   sue    min:  2     max:  32
>   grace  min:  10    max:  45
>   john   min:  14    max:  89

Then I compared it to the given answer provided by the site (I rewrite it in my style):

```
xFile = open("studentdata.txt", "r")

for xLine in xFile:
    xList = xLine.split()
    print(xList[0],"\tmin: ",min(xList[1:]),"\tmax: ",max(xList[1:]))

xFile.close()
```

Which is more simple, but it produce slightly different (but vital) result:

> joe    min:  10    max:  40
>   bill   min:  16    max:  23
>   sue    min:  11    max:  9
>   grace  min:  10    max:  45
>   john   min:  14    max:  89

Notice that the result for **sue** is different. The 'automatic' version doesn't produce the right result. How this happened?

Thanks.

Comment: The automatic version (as you coined it) does compare them as strings, the values, and as strings 9 is "greater" than 11 - nano seconds earlier @niemmi answered ;-)

Comment: It's clear up. thanks! However, I tried to modify last command:    print(xList[0],"\tmin: ",min(int(xList[1:])),"\tmax: ",max(int(xList[1:]))), received this error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' .. Apparently max/min doen't support 'list' mode. So the first (manual) answer is the right one. How can I simplify this? Thanks

Comment: Ah no, you cannot cast a list of strings to an int by giving it as argument to the int() method, the int cast is what you have to do when reading in the list ;-) you can well use min and max on a list of ints - sample min([int(x) for x in xList[1:]])

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the second version is that it doesn't convert the scores to `int` before comparison. When comparing strings `'32'` comes before `'9'`.

You can fix the issue by converting the scores to `int` before using `min` and `max`:

```
with open("studentdata.txt", "r") as xFile:
    for xLine in xFile:
        xList = xLine.split()
        scores = [int(x) for x in xList[1:]]
        print(xList[0],"\tmin: ",min(scores),"\tmax: ",max(scores))
```

Comment: Code looks nice, but I got "TypeError: a is undefined"

Description
Type errors most often occur when an expression tries to combine two objects with types that should not be combined. Like raising a string to a power

Comment: @NunNo How did you run it? Did you copy the example data from question as such to `studentdata.txt` and the code exactly as it is from answer to a script under same folder?

Comment: I pasted it directly into the active code in the site. Now it works after i made some modification, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer which is provided on the site computes `min` and `max` taking `lexicographical order` in account. It's just a coincidence that rest of the answers match.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happened because in finding 'minimum' and 'maximum', the numbers are not converted to integer type, they are being taken as string type. You should first convert it using `map` function or other as per your convenience.

I did this and it worked-

```
print(xList[0],"\tmin: ",min(list(map(int, xList[1:]))),"\tmax: ",max(list(map(int, xList[1:]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the input data to integers and it should work. Python has the simple "int()" method for that which you have already used in the first version. The thing  is, that then comparing strings python uses alphabetical order. For example: "100000000" is less then "2". However int("100000000") is more then int("2") which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The second one compares them as strings, and strings are compared lexicographically by the first character of the string, for example '6' < '58' this is False, and this '8' > '234' is True.